# Queue print jobs in a separate single Thread for JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, concurrency, queue

currently I am experimenting with Concurrency in Java/JavaFX. Printing must run in a different thread otherwise it will make the JavaFX main thread freeze for a couple seconds. Right now my printing is done with this simplified example.

```
public void print(PrintContent pt) {
    setPrintContent(pt);

    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // send content to printer
}
```

With this code I am sending many print jobs parallel to my printer. Therefore I get the error telling me that my printer can only handle 1 print job at a time. Since I know that Threads cannot be reused, I would like to know if there is a possibility to queue up Threads, so that my printer only handles one print job at a time.

Thank you very much for your effort and your time.

Comment: Note that, apart from the problem of sending multiple print jobs to the printer, your code also suffers from multiple threads attempting to access the same state. By calling `setPrintContent(pt)` each call to `print(...)` is going to set `printContent` to a different value; the threads you create are going to try to access that value at some (indeterminate) point in the future. There's no guarantee the background threads will see the correct print content.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I am getting Exceptions especially when I send 2 and more print jobs successively within a very short time period.

Comment: That wouldn't cause exceptions, it would just cause the wrong thing to be printed. The exceptions are from the issue you already identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ~~> WAY 1

You can implement your own `BlockingQueue` [read this is very useful](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/blocking-queues.html) or use a default implementation from Java libraries [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html)

So after reading the above links,you add a method in your class like

```
public void addJob(Object job){   
  queue.put(job); 
}
```

Secondly you implement a Thread that is running into an infinite while loop.Inside it you call the method

```
queue.take();
```

When the queue is empty this Thread is blocked waiting until a new Object is added,so you dont have to worry about spending cpu time.

Finally you can set some upper bounds so for example queue can contain .. 27 items.

Mention that in case of Thread failure you have to recreate it manually.

> ~~>WAY 2 Better Approach

You can use an Executors Interface:

```
ExecutorService executorService1 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

From documentation:

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an
>   unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates
>   due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will
>   take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) Tasks are
>   guaranteed to execute sequentially, and no more than one task will be
>   active at any given time.

With the method below you retrieve a result if the job has successfully done.

```
Future future = executorService.submit(new Callable(){ public Object call() throws Exception { System.out.println("Asynchronous Callable"); return "Callable Result"; } });

 System.out.println("future.get() = " + future.get());
```

If future.get() returns null, the job has been done successfully.

Remember to call 
 `executorService.shutdown();`  because the active threads inside this ExecutorService may prevent the JVM from shutting down.

Full tutorial [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html)

Comment: Hi GoXr3Plus, thank you for your hint. While reading about Executer I also came across BlockingQueue. Could you tell me why you would think that Executer is the better approach or what is the main difference between these two?

Comment: @Chiggidi Executor implementations internally are using some kind of BlockingQueue.I wanted to so you how you can implement your own.After all using the second way is just some lines of code instead of implementing your own.Basically everything you need to know is on the links.

Comment: @Chiggiddi "What is the difference between an executor and a blocking queue"? An executor executes `Runnable`s. A blocking queue simply places items in a queue (but doesn't do anything with them). A single thread executor executes `Runnable`s on a single thread, and (as GoXr3Plus states) internally uses a blocking queue when one runnable has to wait for another to finish. (So, basically, single thread executor implements Way 1 above for you, and does a lot more, such as handling failures of the runnables, etc.)

Comment: @James_D Hi guys, today I implemented the ExecutorService and it has been running quite well through tests. Could you tell me if the order of which Runnables are executed by the Executor (Singelton) is FIFO based, so the first Runnable that goes into the Executor will be executed first?

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--), it's backed by a queue. By definition, a queue is FIFO. So if there is a happens-before relationship between two calls to `execute()`, then the `Runnable` passed to `execute` in the first call is guaranteed to be executed before the `Runnable` passed to `execute` in the second call.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [single threaded executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) to execute the print jobs. It will create one (and only one) background thread and queue the jobs:

```
// it might be better not to make this static; but you need to ensure there is
// only one instance of this executor:
private static final Executor PRINT_QUEUE = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

// ...

public void print(PrintContent pt) {

    PRINT_QUEUE.execute(() -> {
        // send content to printer
    });
}
```